# Angular2 typescript drag and drop feature

Tags: typescript, angular

Anyone already tried drag and drop feature with Angular2 RC with typescript?

Cheers 
Sanket

Comment: Please include more details, what do you want to drag and drop, If you have tried something which is not working, or if you have some feature which you have already implemented and want to be replicated in Angular2 TypeScript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For angular2 , implementing drag and drop is made quite simple:
Following are the alternatives that you can go for implementing drag and drop in angular2.

- [ng2-dragula](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-dragula)
- [angular2-grid](https://github.com/BTMorton/angular2-grid)

personally I would go for ng2-dragula as it provides more features like dragula-model and more of styling.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Bhushan for both options :).

Comment: @Sanket glad to hear.if your query has been resolved then close the question by accepting any of the answers.